# How to split dataset without specific domain knowlege of the dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, dataset, image-processing

I have a medical image dataset that contains about 150 patients and it is possible that there are multiple images from the same patient. So, to use a machine learning (or deep learning in my case) model, I need to split the dataset. Therefore, I randomly split the dataset by patient, i.e., images from the same patient will only be one of training/validation/testing sets, to around 50% training, 25% validation and 25% testing for a classification task.

However, after trying 6 different random seed, I obtain 6 trained models (using identical and common hyperparameters). And their performance on their own testing set ranges from 0.40 to 0.75 kappa. How should I interpret these results?

One conjecture I have is that the randomness could assign the easy patient to the testing (so we get 0.75 kappa) and assign the difficult patients to testing set (so we get 0.40). I could not verify this idea since I do not have the domain knowledge for the images.

Details of the testing results are in Table 1.

`{Splits} & {Class 1 Accuracy} & {Class 2 Accuracy} & {Class 3 Accuracy} & {Class 4 Accuracy} & {Class 5 Accuracy} & {Overall Accuracy} & {Overall Kappa} \\ \midrule
A& 99.33\% & 77.31\% & 73.33\% & 100.00\% & 73.21\% & 82.13\% & 0.7579 \\
B& 83.34\% & 73.31\% & 72.68\% & 16.62\% & 75.50\% & 57.26\% & 0.4837 \\
C& 94.45\% & 43.60\% & 74.01\% & 98.19\% & 69.83\% & 70.24\% & 0.5873 \\
D& 63.63\% & 87.52\% & 61.08\% & 98.31\% & 71.62\% & 75.02\% & 0.6437 \\
E& 61.61\% & 91.65\% & 39.08\% & 99.16\% & 54.48\% & 59.12\% & 0.4278 \\
F& 76.81\% & 23.26\% & 75.06\% & 37.57\% & 63.97\% & 52.45\% & 0.4086 \\`

Answer (score 0):

If it's not very costly, it's always preferable to run cross-validation to alleviate impact of dataset split, which is exactly what you need.

Otherwise, you may try to cluster data points by their embeddings produced by a pre-trained embeddding netowrk such as resnet, then split your dataset in the aid of these clusters.